# One form two submit buttons

Tags: php, forms

I have two similar forms on a site that I'd like to merge into one form with two submit buttons. They use most of the same data.

The first form uses GET to send the data to another server. The second form sends it in an email. I'd like to strongly encourage site users to use option one before trying option two.

I know how to do this with javascript, but not in a way that degrades well. Any other ways to have two submit options? Or other ideas for how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: You can literally use two submit buttons, with different names or values, and check for the action you want to do depending on the $_POST variable(s) matching the buttons you defined.

Comment: Why not just have one submit button and then a couple of radio buttons for the user to pick from? Then process it on the server side. Two submit buttons may be confusing to your visitors.

Comment: Lots of people are suggesting using a dropdown/radio within the form, so I think I should give more detail. The form is for a library. The first form looks to see if the library has an item, the second form emails a librarian and asks her to order it. People have been skipping the first form, which is why I want to merge them. My plan was to style the first submit button to say something like "Please check here before submitting your request." I think Nikola's solution should work for this?

Answer (score 2):

*Snow Blind* provided the good solution, but you can't determine which button was clicked.
Buttons must have different names, not the same.
**Example:**

```
<input type="submit" name="server" value="Server" />
<input type="submit" name="email" value="Email" />

<?php

if(isset($_GET['server']))
{
    // Send to another server
}
else if(isset($_GET['email']))
{
    // Send to email
}
else die("None of buttons was clicked.");

?>
```

Additionally, if you have a same code in both parts (server and email), you can do the following:

```
if(isset($_GET['server']) || isset($_GET['email']))
{
    // Do something common to both methods
    if(isset($_GET['server'])) 
    {
        // Send to server
    }
    else 
    {
        // Send to email
    }
}
```

---

Better solution, in my opinion, is to put only 1 submit button + a dropdown menu with method to choose.

```
<select name="sendMethod">
    <option value="" disabled>Choose sending method...</option>
    <option value="server">Send to another server</option>
    <option value="email">Send to e-mail</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everybody said use either checkbox/radio button. 
And set the one that use GET as the default option

If you don't want to use javascript you can always get the value and of the checkbox/radio and check user choice

Answer (score -1):

You can create two submit buttons and give them the same `name` but different `value`.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Server">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Email">
```

Then you can check `$_GET['submit']` or `$_POST['submit']` (depending on `form method`) to see which submit was used.